# plot least-square regression line in the log-log scale plot

Tags: python, numpy, regression, least-squares

I want to plot the least-square regression line for the X and Y in the log-log scale plot and find coefficients. The line function is log(Y) = a.log(X) + b equivalently, Y = 10^b . X^a. What are
the coefficients a and b? how can I use polyfit in NumPy?

I use code below using [this code](https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-regression-using-least-squares-a4c3456e8570) but I get this runtime error:

> divide by zero encountered in  log10 X_log = np.log10(X)

```
X_log = np.log10(X)
Y_log = np.log10(Y)
X_mean = np.mean(X_log)
Y_mean = np.mean(Y_log)
num = 0
den = 0
for i in range(len(X)):
    num += (X_log[i] - X_mean)*(Y_log[i] - Y_mean)
    den += (X_log[i] - X_mean)**2
m = num / den
c = Y_mean - m*X_mean
print (m, c)
Y_pred = m*X_log + c
plt.plot([min(X_log), max(X_log)], [min(Y_pred), max(Y_pred)], color='red') # predicted
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you say your setup? numpy version and python version

Comment: Probably it is because there is a 0 in X but in higher versions of numpy it doesn't give this error

Comment: version of numpy is 1.17.2 and version of python is 3.7.4 @Bruno Mello

Comment: Can you provide a link to the data?

Comment: Dataset is in http://snap.stanford.edu/data/wiki-Vote.html
It is a network and X is list of node degree and Y is degree distribution. And I plot degree distribution in log-log scale.@Bruno Mello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have X-values that are too close to zero, can you show the values you send to log_x = np.log10(x)?

To use np.polyfit just write

```
coeff = np.polyfit(np.log10(x), np.log10(y), deg = 1)
```

coeff will now be a list [a,b] with your coefficients for a first-degree fit (hence deg = 1) to the data points (log(x), log(y)). If you want the variance in the coefficients use

```
coeff, cov = np.polyfit(np.log10(x), np.log10(y), deg = 1, cov = True)
```

cov is now your covariance matrix.

Comment: X is send to np.log10(X) and X is :[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, ...... , 599, 618, 732, 743, 773, 893]

Comment: you cannot take log of 0, so your first value has to go (or you can set it to 1e-16)